# Displaying a bootstrap Modal dialog from Angular Controller

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to figure out how I can present a bootstrap modal dialog from my Angular controller. Basically what I have is a table. When the user clicks on a table row I want to present a modal dialog that contains details about the selected row.

The way I'm thinking about approaching this is have each table row respond to an ng-click. The ng-click will call a function in the controller and this function will present the modal dialog as well as pass it the data it needs to display.

I know how to display a modal dialog from the view itself, but I'm not sure how I can trigger the modal from the controller. Any ideas?

The controller, for the view, has the following function which will be called when the user selects a row to view a modal dialog.

```
$scope.rowClicked = function(rowID){
    $scope.dataForModal = Data.get(rowID, function(err,data){
        //Here is where I'd like to display the modal dialog in the view
    });
}
```

Comment: What you tried? Can you show me your codes?

Comment: **The problem is I'm not sure how I can achieve this** . hmm. You can do what you think. that is correct way.

Comment: Take a look at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and their $modal provider

Comment: What does you current view and controller looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Use a `ng-click="showDetails(item)"` on the cell/row in your view. Then use this code in your controller to show the Modal:

```
$scope.showDetails = function (item) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'yourview.html',
        controller: 'DetailModalController',                       
        resolve: {
            item: function () {
                return  item;
            },                            
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (item) {
        // ok
    }, function () {
        // dismiss
    });
};
```

Your modal controller can be something like this:

```
angular.module('app').controller('DetailModalController', [
    '$scope', '$modalInstance', 'item',
    function ($scope, $modalInstance, item) {

        $scope.item = item;

        $scope.dismiss = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss();
        };

        $scope.close = function () {                    
             $modalInstance.close($scope.item);                       
        };
    };
}]);
```

With `$modalInstance.close($scope.item);` you can pass an object. With `$modalInstance.dismiss();` you dismiss the modal without an object.

Comment: I'm getting a "ReferenceError: $modal is not defined" error. Should I be injecting $modal into the controller? When I inject $modal into the controller I get "Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider".

Comment: That's correct. Be sure to add the angular-ui library from the provided link in your project, otherwise you will not be able to inject it as can be seen in the error.